# Too many re-render errors in react-native using expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting an error randomly when I start my expo app and it says:

[image: Error messages]

It says that the error is here and I am not sure what is causing it. (it wasn't there before)

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import AccountScreen from "./src/screens/AccountScreen";
import CreateScreen from "./src/screens/CreateScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ItemDetailScreen from "./src/screens/ItemDetailScreen";
import SigninScreen from "./src/screens/SigninScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./src/screens/SignupScreen";
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from "./src/context/AuthContext";
import { setNavigator } from "./src/navigationRef";

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    itemListFlow: createStackNavigator({
      Home: HomeScreen,
      ItemDetail: ItemDetailScreen
    }),
    Create: CreateScreen,
    Account: AccountScreen
  })
});

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App 
        ref={navigator => {
          setNavigator(navigator)
        }}
      />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The app renders, then the `App` component calls `setNavigator` with its current ref, then rerenders as a result of whatever is going in your `setNavigator` function, and repeats forever until the call stack reaches a maximum depth.

It's difficult to answer exactly what's going on without being able to look at that function. But in general, you shouldn't have to use the ref at all anyway. Simply `<App />` should be fine from what I can see, since you already initialize it as a `switchNavigator`.

Comment: What page would you like to see so I can send it I really don't know what to do